# is it possible to use the CD4013 IC inverted output while in frequency divider setup ?

Tags: flipflop, frequency-divider

I am not having success with using the "not Q" output of the CD4013
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4013b.pdf
when the CD4013 is connected for frequency dividing as below:

[image]
I need both Q and "not Q" to drive an H bridge, and I'd save adding a "not gate" if I could  use the "not Q". So how could I do it ?
When I wire the "not Q" to my mosfet driver (IR2184) the whole CD4013 stops working (even if I put a 10k resistor in between the 2 ICs), but I can get it to work at low frequency when my finger touches the CD4013  and my feet touch the ground.

Comment: 4013's can toggle from reflected glitches applied to the output.  Learn how to control stray impedances, conducted and radiated CM noise, and use twisted pairs if long wires. IT will make sense to learn these concepts from a good book on CMOS design and EMI from the best, EMI by Henry Ott. and comprehend as quickly as you can.  ALL OF IT.

Comment: You'll need to add your exact schematic. It is fine to drive a logic input with Qbar, something else is happening

Comment: I cant find any reference schematic were Q bar is used while connected to D on google

Comment: I had a 2k Ohm resistor between the power supply and the CD4013 VCC in order to lower the voltage from the 7v of the supply to about 6V given that the CD4013 uses about 1ma according to the datasheet.
Turns out removing the resistor works much better when using Q bar.

Comment: "CD4013 uses about 1ma" - no it does not! If you need to drop the voltage then use a voltage regulator.

Comment: DC supply can be up to 20V, so why are you using a 2k resistor.  Data sheet shows 5V, 10V and 15V as source.

Comment: I needed the output of the CD4013 to be closer to 5V, but it's output was about the same as VCC, that is 7V. Datasheet showed minimum/typical current of 1mA when the supply was 5V. Putting the 2k ohm did drop the Voltage by 1V. But the voltage drop on VCC was dependent on the high/low  status of the output. My multimeter probably misses some event on VCC (perhaps when Q bar is connected to D, the current is much higher at times  making VCC go too low because of the 2k resistor).
lesson learned that voltage should not be regulated with resitors for devices with variable current consumption.